# Vuetify 3 text color not changing after set bg-color

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to set both `bg-color` and also `text-white` to a simple button, but once background color is set, there's no way I can change text color without creating a class and define the color as `!important`

```html
<v-btn flat class="bg-pink text-white">
  <v-icon color="white">mdi-email</v-icon>
  <span>Click</span>
</v-btn>
```

The following link shows the code result screenshot

[Click to check code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu9Nv.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested the code with version `vuetify@3.0.0-alpha.12` and `vuetify@3.0.0-beta.3` and it works fine, maybe you have other css selector affecting the text color! Try inspecting the text style and look for `color` attribute to find the problem

Comment: @EduardoLourenço I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement.

Comment: I tried beta.3 and worked for me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Rohìt Jíndal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4116300/roh%C3%ACt-j%C3%ADndal) I changed the version to vuetify@3.0.0-beta.3 and the problem was solved. Probably it was one of the many fixes they did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<v-btn outlined flat color="primary">
    <v-icon dense color="error">mdi-email</v-icon>
    <span class="white--text"> Click </span>
</v-btn>
```

When using vuetify, bootstrap classes would conflict with vuetify classes. So you better choose vuetify classes which are of course different from bootstrap classes. Take a look at vuetify documentation for more.

Comment: The text color were white! But the outlined didn't work

Comment: I have edited my code take a look

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `bg-{color}` class for background color and text color by using `text-{color}` class. Here is the full [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/) on color pallete.

Demo **:**

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@3.0.0-next-20220611.0/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@3.0.0-next-20220611.0/dist/vuetify.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center">
        <v-btn class="bg-pink">
          <v-icon class="text-white">mdi-email</v-icon>
          <span class="text-white">Click</span>
        </v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```